I got the openssl extension error when creating new laravel project
Im trying to create a new laravel project and i got the openssl extension error, In Factory.php line 654:
The openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS protection but is not available. If you can not enable the openssl ex
tension, you can disable this error, at your own risk, by setting the 'disable-tls' option to true.
I tried uncommenting the openssl extension from the php.ini file but no solution
